# Understanding tables in html / css

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I am trying to understand tables in html / css, but I don't understand anything of it. I have a lot of questions about it, but i will start with the first one.

Here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

they are saying in case of "table-layout: fixed;":

"The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells"

Okay....so it does not depend on the contents of the cell? Let's test it:

I made a table with table-layout: fixed and I gave one column a width of 200px (inline css in the html):

```css
.myTable {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myTable th, 
.myTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable" style="width: auto; table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th>Column A</th>
    <th style="width: 200px">Column B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1: This is a sentence with a very long word in it, to check what the behavior is of the table in a case like that. Will long words be broken and wrap onto the next line? Thisisaverylongwordyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Why that column with width 200px is now bigger than 200px? If the width would not depend on the contents of the cell then I would expect a width of 200px. In this case i would expect that the long word could overflow, but now the table / column is adjusting its width.

Can anyone tell me how this is working and why it's working like that? I know I can solve it with things like word-wrap: break-word; but I want to understand it.

Comment: @j08691 Sure thanks. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Because you included a long line of unbroken text. By default the browser won't break up that text unless you tell it to with a rule like `word-break:break-all;`. So it does work as expected, you're just giving it text that it doesn't want to break because that's the default behavior. You'll also see if you remove that long unbroken string of text that the column is 200px wide.

```css
.myTable {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.myTable th, 
.myTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable" style="width: auto; table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <th>Column A</th>
    <th style="width: 200px">Column B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>B1: This is a sentence with a very long word in it, to check what the behavior is of the table in a case like that. Will long words be broken and wrap onto the next line? Thisisaverylongwordyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitisyesitis</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please don't confuse the [W3](http://w3.org) with w3schools.com. They're not related in any way.

Comment: My comment is too long and i did not know how to put a fiddle in it, so i posted the comment as "another answer to the question". There i give a reply to your answer, because i think it's not 100% correct, but correct me if i am wrong. My comment is too long and i did not know how to put a fiddle in it, so i posted the comment as "another answer to the question". There i give a reply to your answer, because i think it's not 100% correct, but correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Because you set both a width on the table and the table's layout to fixed. And you should probably delete the answer you posted since it's not an answer but another question.

Comment: It's also not really another question, because it's a comment on your answer. Or do i have to make a new post with both posts combined? And indeed i set both, but in the first situation i set also both (table-layout: fixed and column width). So why they maintain the table width in the second fiddle and why they don't maintain the column width in the first fiddle?

Comment: One example sets a width and layout on the table, the other sets the width on the cell, not the table. Setting the layout to fixed and width on the table will force the width and cause the overflow.

Comment: I understand that, but then i still don't understand it ;). Are you saying that "table-layout: fixed" is only working on the table width and not the column width? Then i could understand it, but on W3Cschools they are saying: "The horizontal layout only depends on the table's width and the width of the columns, not the contents of the cells"?

Comment: Maybe the use of the word table-layout is confusing, Probably they mean that the width of the table is fixed? I thought "layout" are also the columns etcetera, so if i would give a column a width then it's also fixed, but that's not true? So i have to see "fixed" only in relation to the width of the table and not columns? Is that correct? That would clarify a lot...they could make that a bit more clear in the documentation of W3Cschools if that's the case.

Comment: Sorry for the different replies after each other. Everytime i try to add "at j08691" at the beginning of the comment, but if i post it, it's gone. So one last try ;)...now i don't know if you know i was commenting on you.